# Definition of determinant

Tags: determinant

Where can I find explanations on how determinants get defined.  For instance how could one get to the definition provided by Leibniz formula ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants

Comment: There is this new search engine called Google that may be of help.

Comment: @Joe Great name.

Comment: If I had found things satisfactory on the new search engine.  Question closed by idiots and have no clue how to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I recently taught the definition of determinant following the book by Sheldon Axler *Linear Algebra Done Right*, I think that the Leibniz formula is very well explained there.

Comment: Axler is an interesting choice because he [famously advocates](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/Axler-Ford-1996.pdf) delaying determinants as much as possible in linear algebra, proving almost nothing using them. So when he finally does define them, you can bet he's thought carefully about which way is best for his present needs.

Comment: Shall have a look at Axler.

Comment: I also support delaying determinants.